# PROJ4 Library error in combination with MapServer 6 and CentOS 6

Tags: wms, mapserver, proj, epsg, centos

I have recently compiled MapServer 6.2 on a CentOS 6.3 machine. Since I compiled it `--with-proj=/usr`, all the PROJ4 related stuff resides in `/usr/share/proj`.

I've also installed proj4 with `yum install proj`, which installed PROJ4-Version 4.7.0.1.

I wanted to establish a simple WMS Server but ended up having these `"no system list, errno: 2 "` errors when issuing a GetMap-Request.

Weirdly, my PROJ4-Installation did not establish any epsg-File in `/usr/share/proj`, so I downloaded the current source of PROJ4 and extracted the epsg file from there and copied it to `/usr/share/proj/epsg` - after that I am getting similar errors, just with `errno: 20` instead of `errno: 2`.

Here is my mapfile: [wms.map](http://pastebin.com/6avQZUMt)

This is the request I am getting errors with:

```
http://*.*.ch/wms?map=wms.map&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=Axis_NS&STYLES=&SRS=EPSG:21781&WIDTH=400&HEIGHT=300&FORMAT=image/png&BBOX=591800,185500,615000,201000
```

How can I debug this, and why did my PROJ4-Package not have an EPSG File included? Notice there is also no /nad-Folder, just two files nad27 and nad83 as well as nad.lst.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [PROJ_LIB](http://mapserver.org/errors.html#setting-the-location-of-the-epsg-file) parameter must point to a directory.

```
    STATUS ON
    CONFIG "PROJ_LIB" "/usr/share/proj/"
    SIZE 400 300
```

Appropriately: *errno 20* (ENOTDIR) means "not a directory"

Comment: That did the trick, thanks. Still, from where do you know the meaning of those errno's?

Comment: Google 'errno 20' or open *errno.h* in an editor

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on CentOS 7 and found that the files related to EPSG is located in the proj-epsg package. When installed, this package provides the missing epsg file in /usr/share/proj/.